# Laravel 5.4: groupBy on for-loop not working as expected

Tags: php, laravel, for-loop, laravel-blade

Here is my controller first it's very important to see this controller

```
public function index( Request $request ) {
        $dateFrom = $request->get( 'dateFrom' );
        $dateTo   = $request->get( 'dateTo' );
        $status   = $request->get( 'orderState' );

        $orders = ( new OrderList() )
            ->whereHas( 'orderDetail', function ( $query ) {
                $query->where( 'supplier_id', Auth::guard( 'supplier' )->user()->id );
            } )
            ->with( 'deliveryList' )
            ->when( $dateFrom, function ( $query ) use ( $dateFrom, $dateTo ) {
                $query->whereBetween( 'created_at', [ $dateFrom, $dateTo ] );
            } )
            ->when( $status, function ( $query ) use ( $status ) {
                $query->where( 'order_state_id', $status )->get();
            } )->get();

        //Order Status
        $orderStates = OrderState::listsTranslations( 'states' )->pluck( 'states', 'id' )->toArray();


        return view( 'supplierComponents.order_list', compact( 'orders', 'orderStates' ) );
    }
```

and here is also the Models for `OrderList` and `OrderDetail`

```
class OrderList extends Model {
    protected $fillable = [
        ......
        ......
    ];
    public function orderDetail() {
        return $this->hasMany( OrderDetail::class, 'order_id' );
    }

    public function ....
    ....................
    }
}

class OrderDetail extends Model {
    protected $fillable = [
        ......
        ......
    ];

    public function orderId() {
        return $this->belongsTo( OrderList::class, 'order_id' );
    }

    public function productId() {
        return $this->belongsTo( Product::class, 'product_id' );
    }
}
```

Now I am trying to do groupby in the blade file

```
@foreach($orders as $order)
     @foreach($order->orderDetail->groupBy('product_id') as $items)
       <tr>
         <td>{!! $items->sum('quantity') !!}</td>
         <td>{!! $items->first()->product_name !!}</td>
         <td>{!! $items->first()->product_id !!}</td>
       </tr>
     @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Now the results of this array is coming like

```
-------------------------------------------
product-name   |  quantity  |  product-id | 
-------------------------------------------
Coffey         |     2      |      15     |
Coffey         |     1      |      15     |
Coffey         |     1      |      15     |
tea            |     3      |      22     |
tea            |     2      |      22     |
tea            |     1      |      22     |
-------------------------------------------
```

which I need it to be something like

```
-------------------------------------------
product-name   |  quantity  |  product-id | 
-------------------------------------------
Coffey         |     4      |      15     |
tea            |     6      |      22     |
-------------------------------------------
```

**Update**

when debug on orders that what I get.

```
Collection {#708 ▼
  #items: array:14 [▼
    0 => OrderList {#717 ▼
      #fillable: array:4 [▶]
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: null
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:6 [▶]
      #original: array:6 [▶]
      #casts: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #events: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: array:5 [▼
        "deliveryList" => null
        "orderedUsers" => User {#756 ▶}
        "orderedStates" => OrderState {#763 ▶}
        "orderDetail" => Collection {#782 ▶}
        "address" => CustomerAddressBook {#791 ▶}
      ]
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
    }
    1 => OrderList {#718 ▶}
    2 => OrderList {#719 ▶}
    3 => OrderList {#720 ▶}
    4 => OrderList {#721 ▶}
```

How to achieve this

Comment: When you `dd($orders);` what do you have returned? An `Illuminate\Support\Collection` or an `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection`? Or an `OrderList` object?

Comment: as far as I understood you question it returns `OrderList` object and each object has it's own `attributes` and `relations`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding **groupBy** and **select** in your **orderDetail** relationship.

```
              $orders = ( new OrderList() )
                   ->whereHas( 'orderDetail', function ( $query ) {
                       $query->where( 'supplier_id', Auth::guard( 'supplier' )->user()->id );
                       $query->groupBy( 'product_id' );
                       $query->select(DB::raw( "SUM(quantity) as quantity_total" ));
            } )
```

And the **quantity_total** will be holding the total quantity.

Hope that helps.

Comment: No I don't want to touch this query as it is doing another work on the same page

Answer (score 0):

As you are returning an object of type `OrderList` rather than `Collection` then you will not have access to the `groupBy()` method.

If you want to apply a `groupBy()` clause to the underlying query you can do so by accessing the query builder like so:

`$order->orderDetail()->groupBy('product_id')`

### Update

When you have access to a `Collection` (`Eloquent` or `Support`), you can group by properties of the objects in your list like so:

`$order->groupBy('product_id');`

However, in your case I think you are actually wanting to group by properties of related objects. You can do this using the `.` notation like so:

`$order->groupBy('orderDetail.product_id')`

Comment: Thanks for clearing this for me, but I try this solution adding this line like this `@foreach($orders as $order)
 @foreach($order->orderDetail()->groupBy('product_id') as $items)<tr>
     <td>{!! $items->sum('quantity') !!}</td>
     <td>{!! $items->first()->product_name !!}</td>
     <td>{!! $items->first()->product_id !!}</td>
</tr>
     @endforeach
@endforeach` but now it's not showing any thing!!

Comment: still noting showing there after using this `$order->groupBy('orderDetail.product_id')`